# How to create a multi-sig proposal with eosjs?

Tags: eosjs, multisig

I am trying to create a multi-sig proposal (eosio.msig::propose) using eosjs v20.0.0.  The proposed transaction is arbitrary but in my case, I would like to propose an updateauth action.

The equivalent cleos command is:

```
cleos multisig propose changeowner '[{"actor": "alice", "permission": "active"}, {"actor": "bob", "permission": "active"}]' '[{"actor": "master", "permission": "owner"}]' eosio updateauth '{"account": "master", "permission": "owner", "parent": "", "auth": {"keys":[{"key":"EOS6kYgMTCh1iqpq9XGNQbEi8Q6k5GujefN9DSs55dcjVyFAq7B6b", "weight":1}],"threshold":1,"accounts":[],"waits":[]}}"}' -p alice@active
```

Where the `master` account is a multi-sig between alice and bob like

```
master
permissions:
    owner 2:    1 alice@active, 1 bob@active
        active 1:    1 ACTIVE_PUBLIC_KEY
```

My attempt to do with eosjs is following:

```
account = alice;
actionName = 'propose';
actionData = {
  proposer: account,
  proposal_name: 'changeowner',
  requested: [
    {
      'actor': account,
      'permission': 'active'
    },
    {
      'actor': 'bob',
      'permission': 'active'
    }
  ],
  trx: {
    expiration: '2020-04-22T16:39:15',
    ref_block_num: 0,
    ref_block_prefix: 0,
    max_net_usage_words: 0,
    max_cpu_usage_ms: 0,
    delay_sec: 0,
    context_free_actions: [],
    actions: [
      {
        account: 'eosio',
        name: 'updateauth',
        authorization: [
          {
            actor: account,
            permission: 'active'
          }
        ],
        data: {
          account: account,
          permission: 'owner',
          parent: '',
          auth: {
            keys: [
              {
                key: 'EOS6kYgMTCh1iqpq9XGNQbEi8Q6k5GujefN9DSs55dcjVyFAq7B6b',
                weight: 1
              }
            ],
            threshold: 1,
            accounts: [],
            waits: []
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    transaction_extensions: []
  }
};

try {
    const result = await api.transact({
    actions: [{
        account: 'eosio.msig',
        name: actionName,
        authorization: [{
        actor: account,
        permission: 'active',
        }],
        data: actionData,
    }]
    }, {
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30
    });

    console.log(result);
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught exception: ' + e);
    if (e instanceof RpcError) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e.json, null, 2));
    }
}
```

However I get the error:
`Caught exception: Error: Expected string containing hex digits`
because I am passing the action data in `trx` as json and not hex.  Is there a way to pass in json and/or is there a way to convert my json to hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can serialize an action using eosjs `api.serializeActions()`

The documentation should be located here: https://eosio.github.io/eosjs/reference/classes/api.api-1.html#serializeactions

However, I could not find any usage examples until coming across a translated Chinese version of the eosjs documentation here: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://cw.hubwiz.com/card/c/eosjs-manual/1/1/3/&prev=search

Here is the above scenario working from alice's perspective

```js
// CREATE ACTION TO PROPOSE
let actions = [
  {
    account: 'eosio',
    name: 'updateauth',
    authorization: [
      { 
        actor: 'master',
        permission: 'owner',
      }
    ], data: {
      account: 'master',
      permission: 'owner',
      parent: '',
      auth: {
        threshold: 1,
        keys: [
          {
            key: 'EOS6kYgMTCh1iqpq9XGNQbEi8Q6k5GujefN9DSs55dcjVyFAq7B6b',
            weight: 1
          }
        ],
        accounts:[],
        waits:[]
      }
    },
  }
]

let seActions = await api.serializeActions(actions)
console.log(seActions[0].data)


// BUILD THE MULTISIG PROPOSE TRANSACTION
actionData = {
  proposer: 'alice',
  proposal_name: 'changeowner',
  requested: [
    {
      actor: 'alice',
      permission: 'active'
    },
    {
      actor: 'bob',
      permission: 'active'
    }
  ],
  trx: {
        expiration: '2020-04-22T16:39:15',
        ref_block_num: 0,
        ref_block_prefix: 0,
        max_net_usage_words: 0,
        max_cpu_usage_ms: 0,
        delay_sec: 0,
        context_free_actions: [],
        actions: [
          {
            account: 'eosio',
            name: 'updateauth',
            authorization: [
              {
                actor: 'master',
                permission: 'owner'
              }
            ],
            data: seActions[0].data
          }
        ],
        transaction_extensions: []
      }
};

// SEND THE MULTISIG PROPOSE
try {
  const result = await api.transact({
    actions: [{
      account: 'eosio.msig',
      name: 'propose',
      authorization: [{
        actor: 'alice',
        permission: 'active',
      }],
      data: actionData,
    }]
  }, {
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
    broadcast: true,
    sign: true
  });
  console.log(result);

} catch (e) {
  console.log('Caught exception: ' + e);
  if (e instanceof RpcError) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e.json, null, 2));
  }
}
```